# Excel add-in Shared runtime configuration, webpack.config.js is not present in project

Tags: excel, webpack, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I created an Excel Add-in project few months back using Visual Studio 2019. Now I am facing some issues and  came to conclusion that Shared Runtime might not be configured correctly. So I followed this tutorial to update manifest of the project.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial

However after that It is mention to update webpack.config.js, but this file is not present in project. Even if I create a new project using VS2019, this file is not there. Can anyone guide me how to add this file like its location, contents etc so that I can add it and follow next steps to configure Shared Runtime correctly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reply from Rick Kirkham on Github page is below.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/3568#issuecomment-1201573455

> This tutorial creates an add-in project with Yo Office. That kind of
> project runs in Node.js. WebPack is a tool for bundling multiple
> JavaScript files into one. WebPack is only relevant to Node.js based
> projects. Since you created your project in VS 2019, your project uses
> C# or VB.NET on the server side and runs in an IIS server. WebPack is
> not used in that environment. That's why there is no webpack.config.js
> file. Whatever problems you are having with the shared runtime, you're
> not going to solve it with WebPack.
>
> Consider raising your problem on Microsoft Q&A. Be sure to
> "office-addin-dev".
>
> Alternatively, consider recreating your project as a Node.js project.
> You can use this tutorial as a good place to start.

Comment: And I've posted that you need to use yeoman generator instead of VS2019 to use webpack. Why do you repost the same from other sources?

Comment: I found Rick Kirkham's comment more related to my question. However before posting it here, I waited for him to answer here, but then thought that It might be helpful for others facing same problem, so posted it here also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the VSCode with yeoman generator to scaffold an add-in project which uses webpack for bundling. For example, the [Build an Excel task pane add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-jquery?tabs=yeomangenerator) page contains guides for Visual Studio and Yeoman generator (as a rule VSCode or WebStorm developers).

Comment: I don't need to use webpack, but I found article misleading so asked it here. More appropriate answer would be that VS2019 projects don't need to update webpacks as they run in C#/VB instead of Node.Js

Comment: There are two main IDEs from MS that allow creating Office add-ins. You can see docs for both of them in MSDN. That is confusing I agree, but in my post I clearly stated that you need to use another IDE with yeoman (webpack).